# Returning row# in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, row

`=XLOOKUP(P22&J22,ARRAYFORMULA(B:B&J:J),B:B)`

This returns the value in column B if all criteria are met. I need to return the row # instead.

Example:

`=XLOOKUP(P22&J22,ARRAYFORMULA(B:B&J:J),return row# here)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```cpp
=FILTER(ROW(B:B),P22&J22=B:B&J:J)
```